# button group of a range of dates not calculating correctly in Angular code

Tags: angularjs

I have the following button group:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" data-btn-radio="'CurrentDateMinus3'">{{dateMinus3 | date:'dd'}}</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" data-btn-radio="'CurrentDateMinus2'">{{dateMinus2 | date:'dd'}}</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" data-btn-radio="'CurrentDateMinus1'">{{dateMinus1 | date:'dd'}}</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" data-btn-radio="'CurrentDate'">{{date | date:'dd'}}</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" data-btn-radio="'CurrentDatePlus1'">{{datePlus1 | date:'dd'}}</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" data-btn-radio="'CurrentDatePlus2'">{{datePlus2 | date:'dd'}}</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" data-btn-radio="'CurrentDatePlus3'">{{datePlus3 | date:'dd'}}</label>
</div>
```

I found following AngularJS code in a StackOverflow question to set the dates:

```
var d = $scope.date = new Date();
$scope.dateMinus1 = d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
$scope.dateMinus2 = d.setDate(d.getDate() - 2);
$scope.dateMinus3 = d.setDate(d.getDate() - 3);
$scope.datePlus1 = d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
$scope.datePlus2 = d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2);
$scope.datePlus3 = d.setDate(d.getDate() + 3);
```

I want button group to display the dates in the following manner (using today's date and setting it as the middle button):

`14 15 16 17 18 19 20`

When I implement this code though, I get the following numbers in the buttons:

`11 14 16 17 12 14 17`

I could use some advice as to what I'm doing wrong. As far as I can tell, the code looks like it should work, but obviously its not. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting dates in another way, because you need a new date each time.

```
var d = $scope.date = new Date();
var dates = [];
// loop to generate dates from -3 days ago to 3 days plus
for(var i=-3; i<= 3; i++){
     var today = new Date();
     dates.push(today.setDate(today.getDate() + i));
}
console.log(dates);
```

Working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3kKxOq7jIUEay9JxLZbg?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

That happens because variable `d` rewrited every time you call `d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1)`. You need to call `new Date()` every time, or find another way to do it. (probably [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) will help you)